# Proportional positioning with jQuery

Tags: jquery, math, positioning

```
function positionElements(){
       var vidHeight = $('#video').height;
       var displace = parseInt(vidHeight, 10) * 0.8;
       var topMargin = displace+'px';
       $('#video-overlay').offset($('#video').offset()).width($('#video').width());
       $('#video-overlay p').css('margin-top', topMargin);
}
```

I'm getting NaN for this.. I thought parseInt was supposed to get me past that. What do I need to do to perform multiplication in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses after the `height`:

```
var vidHeight = $('#video').height();
```

Without them, you are passing in the `height` property of the object, and as that object is an instance of jQuery, the `height` property is simply the jQuery `height` function itself, rather than the result of that function.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 var vidHeight = $('#video').height;
```

Into

```
 var vidHeight = $('#video').height();
```